# Swift 3 class/property reference syntax - Couchbase Lite

Tags: swift, class, reference, couchbase

I'm hoping I can get a little help with some syntax in Swift 3 as I'm fairly new to it and starting to dive into stuff that is just not in the simple books that I read through. I did trying hunting around Google and just seem to have a hard time finding what I'm looking for. I'm trying something with Couchbase Lite.

So in my AppDelegate class, I create a variable, as in "var database: CBLDatabase!"

In "func application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)" I call startSession() and that function calls openDatabase(), which then properly opens my database using:

try database = CBLManager.sharedInstance().openDatabaseNamed(dbname, with: options)

and I can get to the data within the database using a query. At this point, I'm setting up some default global variables and a couple of arrays for use elsewhere in the app.

My app has a few viewcontrollers and in one of them, I want to get back to querying the database. I would like to set up another query using the "database" object that I set up in the AppDelegate class. I thought it would be something like:

let query2 = AppDelegate.database.viewNamed("myquery").createQuery()

but the autofill never finds anything like that as I start typing out the statement. I found some help in other posts but I can never quite seem to get the right syntax.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Edit: I did make "database" a global variable by placing it above the AppDelegate class definition, but I'm not sure that is a best practice and I would like to minimize global variable use.

Comment: Is AppDelegate the name of the class? Then database is an instance variables, you are accessing the static memebers of AppDelegate. For your case making database static could work, i.e `static var Database: CBLDatabase!`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting stuff in the AppDelegate, I would recommend using a singleton pattern for hosting the global variables that you need accessed across your view controllers.Basically have a "DatabaseManager" singleton class that creates the database instance and makes it available to other view controllers.  Refer to this [code snippet](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-mobile-ios-app-extension/blob/master/CBLiteAppExtension/DatabaseManager.swift) as an example.

Comment: Makes total sense. If I were to move all those functions from AppDelegate to this new DatabaseManager.swift class, do I just keep the original code that I had in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function? I basically have: enable logging, logging in, starting the session, and setting the certs.

Comment: It really depends on the functionality. You can implement the actual calls to CB in the DatabaseManager and expose wrapper APIs that will be invoked from AppDelegate or other view controllers .  Some of the functions (like setting certs during replication)  can be done automatically within DatabaseManager when replicator is created